# Replace words from a dictionary

Tags: ruby, string

I have an array of hashes, each hash has two keys : "from" and "to"

```
@dictionary = [{:to=>"lazy", :from=>"quick"}, {:to=>"flies", :from=>"jumps"}, {:from => "over the", :to => "under the"}]
```

I have some long string

```
@text = "quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

How can I replace all occurences of "from" sentences to "to" sentences of the dictionary ?

The output should be:

> lazy brown fox flies under the lazy dog

What is the most efficient way ?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to store the dictionary as a hash? `@dictionary = { 'lazy' => 'quick', 'flies' => 'jumps', 'over the' => 'under the' }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@dictionary.each do |pair|
  @text.gsub!(/#{pair[:from]}/, pair[:to])
end
```

Or if you'd prefer it on a single line:

```
@dictionary.each { |pair| @text.gsub!(/#{pair[:from]}/, pair[:to]) }
```

It's the exact same code, just using `{ }` instead of `do end` for the block (which tends to be the general Ruby practice).

Comment: "all occurences", so instead of `sub` should be `gsub`.

Answer (score 1):

If it would have been only words without the `{"over the"=>"under the"}` then I think something like this would be faster than scanning the string over and over again like most of the solutions here do.

First I convert the array to a pure Hash

```
h=Hash.new
@dictionary.each {|ft| h[ft[:from]]=ft[:to]}
=> {"quick"=>"lazy", "over the"=>"under the", "jumps"=>"flies"}
```

then I scan the string word by word

```
@text.split(/ /).each{|w| h[w] || w}.join(" ")
=> "lazy brown fox flies over the lazy dog"
```

Also it doesn't suffer from the multiple substitution problem.

```
h["brown"]="quick"
=> {"brown"=>"quick", "quick"=>"lazy", "over the"=>"under the", "jumps"=>"flies"}
@text.split(/ /).each{|w| h[w] || w}.join(" ")
=> "lazy quick fox flies over the lazy dog"
```

I did some benchmarks and I had to add a lot more replacement pairs than I thought before the solution above got faster than `gsub!`.

```
require 'benchmark'

@dictionary = [{:to=>"lazy", :from=>"quick"}, {:to=>"flies", :from=>"jumps"}, {:from => "over the", :to => "under the"}]
@text = "quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" * 10000
Benchmark.bm do |benchmark|
  benchmark.report do
    h=Hash.new
    @dictionary.each {|ft| h[ft[:from]]=ft[:to]}
    result=@text.split(/ /).each{|w| h[w] || w}.join(' ')
  end
  benchmark.report do
    @dictionary.each { |pair| @text.gsub!(/#{pair[:from]}/, pair[:to]) }
  end

  @dictionary+=[{:to=>"black", :from=>"brown"}, {:to=>"ox", :from=>"fox"}, {:to=>"hazy", :from=>"lazy"}, {:to=>"frog", :from=>"dog"}]
  @dictionary=@dictionary*15

  benchmark.report do
    h=Hash.new
    @dictionary.each {|ft| h[ft[:from]]=ft[:to]}
    result=@text.split(/ /).each{|w| h[w] || w}.join(' ')
  end
  benchmark.report do
    @dictionary.each { |pair| @text.gsub!(/#{pair[:from]}/, pair[:to]) }
  end
end
```

The results:

```
      user     system      total        real
  0.890000   0.060000   0.950000 (  0.962106)
  0.200000   0.020000   0.220000 (  0.217235)
  0.980000   0.060000   1.040000 (  1.042783)
  0.980000   0.030000   1.010000 (  1.011380)
```

The `gsub!` solution was 4.5 times faster with only three replacement pairs.
At 105 replacement pairs the `split` solution finally is as fast, it actually only got 10% slower with 105 replacement pairs than for three. The `gsub!` got five times slower.

Comment: I don't think `split` and `join` is a good idea. What if `@text = "  lazy quick fox \n flies    over \t the lazy dog"` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@dictionary.inject(@text) {|text, d|
  text.gsub d[:from], d[:to]
}
```

Comment: @dictionary = [{:to=>"crazy bob", :from=>"lazy"}, {:to=>"mad ben", :from=>"crazy bob"}]

"quick brown fox jumps over the mad ben dog"

As You can see, the same text is substituted twice, does anybody knows a one run solution (not overriding previous replacements) ?

Good work @NV, thanks

Comment: What output do you expect? "quick brown fox jumps over the mad ben dog" or not?

Comment: I mean in my previous comment, the first substitution from lazy to crazy bob is later replaced by from crazy bob to mad ben. It should'nt replace existent substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
@enhaced_dictionary = @dictionary.inject({}) {|res, e| res[e[:from]] = e[:to]  }
@compiled = @text.split(/\s/).map do |e|
  @enhaced_dictionary[e] ?  @enhaced_dictionary[e] : e
end.join(' ')
```

Comment: `IndexError: string not matched`